Should an rvalue parameter always get moved?
I've got the below piece of code that causes a warning with clang-tidy.
void process(const std::vector<uint8_t> &buffer)
{
  // ... process the message ...
}

void process(std::vector<uint8_t> &&buffer)
{
    // Warning: rvalue reference parameter 'buffer' is never moved from inside the function body [cppcoreguidelines-rvalue-reference-param-not-moved]
    process(buffer);
}

What is the best practice for this case?

In the second implementation  process(buffer); the "buffer" gets a name and is no longer an r-value reference. Or a different take on it : nothing in the implementation of void process(std::vector<uint8_t> &&buffer) is taking ownership of the buffer. So the warning is correct

@PepijnKramer I didn't say that the warning is incorrect. I just wonder the possible solutions for it.

I see :)  The solution I think is just to remove the rvalue version of process, since that is forwarding to the l-value one anyway (so nothing will be moved). But to be sure we would need to know what your intention with the two overloads is. (It could also mean you need to remove the lvalue one, it all depends on whether you still need the buffer after the process call)

@PepijnKramer My initial purpose was to create a method to process an incoming byte stream. The const reference version was enough for it. Then, I thought that I should add an rvalue version so that the callers can make asynchronous calls without worrying about the copying cost. I would appreciate it if you could criticize this approach as well.

They are both using references, so there is no copying in either. The warning is more about "Why are there two versions if they do the same thing?". The second version could move its parameter, but it does not. So what is the difference?

rvalue reference or not has to do with ownership, not with threading directly. But if you want to hand over the data from one thread to another it makes sense to only have the rvalue reference overload.  See : https://godbolt.org/z/hnWe6YKsG

@PepijnKramer I cannot have only the rvalue overload as the other one can be preferred as well. Shouldn't an API be rich in options?

@BoP The caller should create a copy of the buffer vector if he/she will process it in another thread.

No an API should never be "rich" in options, I have a personal rule : "No convenience functions". But if you want to provide both options, then they probably need optimized implementations.

@CaglayanDokme Not necessarily, either transfer ownership or model shared ownership (e.g. std::shared_ptr). And with std::vector, I wouldn't use value semantics (e.g. copying) it is probably very inefficient.  So it would have to be a move or shared_ptr

Shouldn't an API be rich in options?  No.  The API should be concise and sufficient.  Use YAGNI and KISS to avoid over-engineering.
